# Removing log files doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which I plan to use to delete log files that are over a certain amount of days old

```
$path = "C:\users\example\desktop\test\*"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *txt | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
} | Remove-Item
```

Now the script works fine on test txt files that I have created, but it doesn't work on the log files. The files are just over 400 MB each, so is there a limit on the file size `Remove-Item` can handle? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: `-include *log,*txt`?

Comment: Try adding `-Force`  on `Remove-Item` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @4c74356b41 is probably right, but just to be clear, _what file extensions are not being deleted?_  `*.log`?

Comment: @4c74356b51 was right. Including *log deleted the larger files. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Don't include a wildcard in your path.

```
GCI C:\Users\Example\Desktop\Test -Include *txt |
  ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } |
  Remove-Item -Force
```